# ¿Cual es el archivo .HEX para Compilar Arduino?

Tags: arduino

me podrían ayudar a encontrar cual de estos archivos es el ejecutable de los microcontroladores `.HEX` ?

Este es el resultado de la compilación :

> C:\Program Files\Arduino\arduino-builder -dump-prefs -logger=machine -hardware "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware" -tools "C:\Program Files\Arduino\tools-builder" -tools "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr" -built-in-libraries "C:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries" -libraries "C:\Users\Byron\Documents\Arduino\libraries" -fqbn=arduino:avr:uno -ide-version=10610 -build-path "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp" -warnings=none -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -verbose "C:\Users\Byron\Desktop\LedArduino\LedArduino.ino"
>   C:\Program Files\Arduino\arduino-builder -compile -logger=machine -hardware "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware" -tools "C:\Program Files\Arduino\tools-builder" -tools "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr" -built-in-libraries "C:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries" -libraries "C:\Users\Byron\Documents\Arduino\libraries" -fqbn=arduino:avr:uno -ide-version=10610 -build-path "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp" -warnings=none -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -verbose "C:\Users\Byron\Desktop\LedArduino\LedArduino.ino"
>   Using board 'uno' from platform in folder: C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr
>   Using core 'arduino' from platform in folder: C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr
>   Detecting libraries used...
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics  -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10610 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\sketch\LedArduino.ino.cpp" -o "nul"
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics  -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10610 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\sketch\LedArduino.ino.cpp" -o "nul"
>   Generating function prototypes...
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics  -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10610 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\sketch\LedArduino.ino.cpp" -o "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\preproc\ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp"
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\tools-builder\ctags\5.8-arduino10/ctags" -u --language-force=c++ -f - --c++-kinds=svpf --fields=KSTtzns --line-directives "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\preproc\ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp"
>   Compilando programa...
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10610 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\sketch\LedArduino.ino.cpp" -o "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\sketch\LedArduino.ino.cpp.o"
>   Compiling libraries...
>   Compiling core...
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-gcc" -c -g -x assembler-with-cpp -flto -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10610 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\wiring_pulse.S" -o "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\wiring_pulse.S.o"
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-gcc" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -flto -fno-fat-lto-objects -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10610 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\WInterrupts.c" -o "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\WInterrupts.c.o"
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-gcc" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -flto -fno-fat-lto-objects -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10610 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\hooks.c" -o "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\hooks.c.o"
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-gcc" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -flto -fno-fat-lto-objects -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10610 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\wiring.c" -o "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\wiring.c.o"
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-gcc" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -flto -fno-fat-lto-objects -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10610 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\wiring_analog.c" -o "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\wiring_analog.c.o"
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-gcc" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -flto -fno-fat-lto-objects -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10610 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\wiring_digital.c" -o "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\wiring_digital.c.o"
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-gcc" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -flto -fno-fat-lto-objects -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10610 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\wiring_pulse.c" -o "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\wiring_pulse.c.o"
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-gcc" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -flto -fno-fat-lto-objects -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10610 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\wiring_shift.c" -o "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\wiring_shift.c.o"
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10610 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\CDC.cpp" -o "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\CDC.cpp.o"
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10610 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\HardwareSerial.cpp" -o "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\HardwareSerial.cpp.o"
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10610 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\HardwareSerial0.cpp" -o "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\HardwareSerial0.cpp.o"
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10610 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\HardwareSerial1.cpp" -o "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\HardwareSerial1.cpp.o"
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10610 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\HardwareSerial2.cpp" -o "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\HardwareSerial2.cpp.o"
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10610 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\HardwareSerial3.cpp" -o "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\HardwareSerial3.cpp.o"
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10610 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\IPAddress.cpp" -o "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\IPAddress.cpp.o"
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10610 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\PluggableUSB.cpp" -o "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\PluggableUSB.cpp.o"
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10610 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\Print.cpp" -o "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\Print.cpp.o"
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10610 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\Stream.cpp" -o "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\Stream.cpp.o"
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10610 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\Tone.cpp" -o "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\Tone.cpp.o"
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10610 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\USBCore.cpp" -o "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\USBCore.cpp.o"
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10610 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\WMath.cpp" -o "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\WMath.cpp.o"
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10610 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\WString.cpp" -o "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\WString.cpp.o"
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10610 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\abi.cpp" -o "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\abi.cpp.o"
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10610 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\main.cpp" -o "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\main.cpp.o"
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10610 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\new.cpp" -o "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\new.cpp.o"
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\core.a" "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\wiring_pulse.S.o"
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\core.a" "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\WInterrupts.c.o"
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\core.a" "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\hooks.c.o"
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\core.a" "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\wiring.c.o"
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\core.a" "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\wiring_analog.c.o"
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\core.a" "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\wiring_digital.c.o"
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\core.a" "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\wiring_pulse.c.o"
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\core.a" "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\wiring_shift.c.o"
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\core.a" "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\CDC.cpp.o"
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\core.a" "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\HardwareSerial.cpp.o"
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\core.a" "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\HardwareSerial0.cpp.o"
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\core.a" "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\HardwareSerial1.cpp.o"
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\core.a" "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\HardwareSerial2.cpp.o"
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\core.a" "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\HardwareSerial3.cpp.o"
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\core.a" "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\IPAddress.cpp.o"
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\core.a" "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\PluggableUSB.cpp.o"
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\core.a" "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\Print.cpp.o"
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\core.a" "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\Stream.cpp.o"
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\core.a" "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\Tone.cpp.o"
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\core.a" "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\USBCore.cpp.o"
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\core.a" "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\WMath.cpp.o"
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\core.a" "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\WString.cpp.o"
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\core.a" "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\abi.cpp.o"
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\core.a" "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\main.cpp.o"
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-gcc-ar" rcs  "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\core.a" "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\core\new.cpp.o"
>   Linking everything together...
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-gcc" -w -Os -flto -fuse-linker-plugin -Wl,--gc-sections -mmcu=atmega328p  -o "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp/LedArduino.ino.elf" "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp\sketch\LedArduino.ino.cpp.o" "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp/core\core.a" "-LC:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp" -lm
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-objcopy" -O ihex -j .eeprom --set-section-flags=.eeprom=alloc,load --no-change-warnings --change-section-lma .eeprom=0  "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp/LedArduino.ino.elf" "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp/LedArduino.ino.eep"
>   "C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-objcopy" -O ihex -R .eeprom  "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp/LedArduino.ino.elf" "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp/LedArduino.ino.hex"

El Sketch usa 444 bytes (1%) del espacio de almacenamiento de programa. El máximo es 32.256 bytes.
Las variables Globales usan 9 bytes (0%) de la memoria dinámica, dejando 2.039 bytes para las variables locales. El máximo es 2.048 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando compilas con Arduino, la salda te mostrara varios mensajes, **la última linea te muestra el path del archivo .HEX**, en tu caso sería:

> "C:\Users\Byron\AppData\Local\Temp\build3857690822a41ea6711f5dd7665347d5.tmp/LedArduino.ino.hex"